# c# windows form application dynamic objects value

Tags: c#, winforms, object, visual-studio-2012, dynamic

i have made a mistake of re-inventing the wheel. There are options 
but somehow i like the feel of this.
Sorry but don't have enough rep to post an image.
This is how the form looks like:

SNO.-------ITEMS--------FROM--------TO---------QUANTITY // labels

[ 1 ]-------[-----------▼]---[--------]----[--------]------[-------------] {NEW} {DELETE} //textboxes and buttons

I've got the 'new' button click event to generate a row, and serial number to be automatic
and inserted the items into the collections from Properties panel.
Delete button deletes an entire row and shifts both the button up on Y position.

I need to assign the value of quantity [(TO - FROM ) + 1] in the QUANTITY text boxes, 
for which i have the code as :

```
    public void print_quant(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox quanty;
        quanty = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("QUANTITY" + (count), true)[0];
        calculate_quant(this, e);
        quanty = result;

    }
    public static string result;
    public string calculate_quant(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox sfrom;
        sfrom = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("SFRM" + count, true)[0];

        TextBox sto;
        sto = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("STO" + count, true)[0];

        TextBox quan;
        quan = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("QUANTITY" + count, true)[0];

            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sfrom.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sto.Text))
          {
              int to = Convert.ToInt32(sto.Text);
              int from = Convert.ToInt32(sfrom.Text);
              int quantity = (to - from) + 1;
              result = quantity.ToString();   
              quan.Text = result;
          }
         return result;             
    }
```

count is initialized at 1 on form load, keeps increasing with number of rows

the same code works in the delete row method

```
    public void delete_row(object sender, EventArgs e) //function to delete a row
    {
        TextBox snum;
        snum = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("SNO"+count, true)[0];
        snum.Dispose();
...//delete other row elements
}
```

please help me figure out why it doesnt work for the print_quant / calculate_quant methods

Comment: You didn't reinvent the wheel, you invented a square wheel.  There are so many other better ways of doing this, you might want to reconsider a rewrite.  You are going to have to put a line break into your calculate method and see what is actually going on.    At the end you have result=....  what is that doing? you should have quan.Text=result; after that

Comment: As well your Print method doesn't actually do anything. all it does is run the calculate_quant method... which, doesn't do anything other then assign your addition to the variable "result".

Comment: Sorry i somehow missed that, i do have quan.Text = result; in my code.
result = quantity.ToString() is converting to to string so that textbox.text can accept the value

Comment: so if i add a return result line in calculate function, and assign the textbox.text = result in print_quant it should work right ? let me give a try

Comment: Controls.Find(...)...looks like someone was not using winforms at all before :)

Comment: hehe yes its my first app, poorly written but just works. Had to use Control.Find because generating the rows dynamically , how else can i access them ?
Next time i'll use better methods, that i came across while writing this one

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code.  I changed the return on your calculate method to a string, and added a quanty.Text=calculatemethod line to your print method

```
    public void print_quant(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox quanty;
        quanty = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("QUANTITY" + (count), true)[0];
        //add this line
        quanty.Text = calculate_quant(this, e).ToString();
    }
    public static string result;

    //change this 
    //public void calculate_quant(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //to
    public string calculate_quant(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox sfrom;
        sfrom = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("SFRM" + count, true)[0];

        TextBox sto;
        sto = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("STO" + count, true)[0];

        //this isn't being used here 
        //TextBox quan;
        //quan = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("QUANTITY" + count, true)[0];

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sfrom.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sto.Text))
        {
            int to = Convert.ToInt32(sto.Text);
            int from = Convert.ToInt32(sfrom.Text);
            int quantity = (to - from) + 1;
           return  quantity.ToString();

        }

    }
```

***Edit***
try this.

Create a usercontrol and make it look exactly like one of your rows.

add a property variable for each of the boxes

```
//whenever you Sno="something" the textbox will automatically be updated.

private string _Sno="00000";
public string Sno{get{return _Sno;}set{_sno=value; SnoTextBox.Text=value;}}
```

do this for each of your textboxes.

on your main form now you can add a flowpanel, they a bit tricky at first.  when you add your new Usercontrol to it, they will automatically be added from the top down, or up, or however you set it up.

When you want to add a new row, just add your new Usercontrol to the flowpanel

```
FlowPanel flowPanel =new FlowPanel();

FlowPanel.Controls.Add(new myUserControl());
```

to delete

```
FlowPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(2);
```

This is really poorly written, but I am out of time.  Either ignore me altogether, or try to figure it out.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanx, i made the correction in my code but it's still not displaying anything in the 'quantity' box

Comment: I'm unsure of the result this line implements

     'TextBox sfrom;
        sfrom = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("SFRM" + count, true)[0];'what is the second argument (true)and [0] for ?

Since it worked for finding the row elements for my delete function i used the same code to find the textboxes and their values

Comment: ??  it's your code.  I believe you are getting the Text Property of the TextBox SFRM(count) I wish I had significantly more time to help you out here, this truly is easier then you are doing it. I simply don't have time right now, I hope someone else can help you

Comment: Please suggest something else then, its easier with datagrid view ?i had some trouble binding the items list to it so i skipped it (it's my first attempt towards creating any application ever)
Thanx for bearing with me

Comment: Thanx @K'leg I'll try with this now

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9a3ae2/using-listview-control-windows-form-application3/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox quant;
        int x = count - 1;
        string num = Convert.ToString(x);
        quant = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("QUANTITY" + x , true)[0];
        TextBox to = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("STO" + x, true)[0];
        TextBox from = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("SFRM" + x, true)[0];
        string tovalue = to.Text;
        int to1 = Convert.ToInt32(tovalue);
        string fromvalue = from.Text;
        int from1 = Convert.ToInt32(fromvalue);
        int result = (to1 - from1) + 1 ;
        if (result > 0)
        {
            string result1 = Convert.ToString(result);
            quant.Text = result1;
        }

    }
```

after adding

```
    STO.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
```

at the function that was generating the boxes where i needed to calculate :)